# How to test 3d acceleration?

Tags: 3d, vga

I want to install and test 3d acceleration in Ubuntu 12.

I have read these pages:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection?action=show&redirect=X%2FTroubleshooting%2FFglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver#Problem:_Need_to_purge_-fglrx

I think I have installed it correctly, but I don't know how to test it.

I tried to play minecraft in the browser, but I got a black screen. It may be a java problem too, so I need to troubleshoot.

So how can I test my video card and drivers?

Comment: I suppose that Downloading a 3D game form the Software Center could test 3D performance..but I don't know.

Answer (score 21):

The command below could provide at least a partial answer to your question.

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

The command tests whether your video adapter will support Unity 3D. While it does *not* test 3D acceleration per se, it will at least test for the 3D features which Unity 3D requires.

And, what the heck, it comes with Ubuntu so all you have to do is open a terminal window and run it. ;-)

Here is an example of the output.

```
irrational@VBx64:~$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   Humper
OpenGL renderer string: Chromium
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Chromium 1.9

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

Comment: Is there something equally convenient for Xubuntu?

Comment: I do not see /usr/lib/nux/ on my freshly installed Ubuntu.

Answer (score 12):

An easy way to test it (not a benchmark test though) is using glxgears.

`sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`

then in a terminal type: `glxgears`

It will display your frames per second (fps).

More info [here](http://www.xfree86.org/current/glxgears.1.html).

Comment: I had to type: `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils` to install it and the FPS was synched to my vertical refresh, so it was capped at 60 fps.

Comment: Using glxgears is NOT recommended. It's inaccurate and uninsightful potentiality masking issues.

Comment: @Martin: is there any chance you could add what the recommended test is?

Comment: FWIW, in a VM on a MacBook Pro 17" 2011. Renderer is Gallium, in full screen (1920x1200), I get 450 to 550 fps. In the default size (small) gears window I get 2000 to 3000 fps.