# How to tell if graphics processing in Ubuntu is utilizing hardware acceleration

Tags: graphics, hardware-acceleration

How I could tell if graphics processing (3D, video encode/decude) in Ubuntu is utilizing hardware acceleration (ie. using GPU). Is there a utility that can help?

Comment: This might help [How to test 3d acceleration?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150149/how-to-test-3d-acceleration)

Answer (score 8):

Try the following command if you're running Unity:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

It will tell you if you're using a Software renderer.

Answer (score 4):

you can use glxinfo to test if your X server is using the GPU driver.
glxinfo queries X server about its OpenGL version, renderer string, Visuals supported and other infomation.

```
glxinfo | less
```

Comment: Even I had this doubt. So what am I supposed to look at in the output of this command?

Comment: OpenGL version, vendor string, renderer string. then you'll know if you're running open source drivers or proprietary drivers or software rasterizers.