# 12.04 to 14.04 update slows down the system

Tags: 14.04, performance

I recently updated from 12.04 to 14.04 LTS. But the system is very slow. Everything works, but slowly. What could be the reason?.

I have 4GB RAM, 10GB swap space and 300 GB of hard disk. Also the graphics card used by me is 
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880 [Radeon HD 4250]

Comment: Try [How to test 3d acceleration?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150149/how-to-test-3d-acceleration) and [How do I tell if Ubuntu supports hardware-accelerated graphics on my laptop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33873/how-do-i-tell-if-ubuntu-supports-hardware-accelerated-graphics-on-my-laptop)